# Show that the lexicographic ordering $≤_l$ on $A\times B$ for $A$ well ordered by $≤$ and $B$ well-ordered by $≤'$ is well-ordered.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Q: Show that the lexicographic ordering $≤_l$ on $A\times B$ for $A$ well ordered by $≤$ and $B$ well-ordered by $≤'$ is well-ordered.

A: I have previously shown that this lexicographic ordering is totally ordered, and I am aware that any finite totally ordered set is well-ordered, but $A$ and $B$ aren't necessarily finite, so I'm not sure how to show that any subset of $A\times B$ has a least element.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Go component by component. If $C\subset A\times B$ is non-empty, then its projection onto the first component is a non-empty subset of $A$. Therefore, this projection has a minimum $a$. Take the subset of $C$ of elements that have $a$ as their first component. This set is non-empty. Look at the projection onto the second component. This is a non-empty subset of $B$, which therefore, has a minimum $b$. Then $(a,b)\in C$. Show that $(a,b)$ is the minimum of $C$, and therefore $C$ has a minimum.

Comment: @user647486.  Let A = {0,1} = B, C = { (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) }.  Notice that (0,0) is not the minimum as you claimed.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Run the algorithm that I said. Notice why you ran it wrong if you got $(0,0)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi_A: A \times B \to A$ and $\pi_B: A \times B \to B$ be the projection maps.

Suppose $C \subseteq A \times B$ is non-empty, then $\pi_A[C]$ is a non-empty subset of $A$ and so has a $\le$-minimal element $a_0 \in \pi_A[C]$.

Then the set $(\{a_0 \} \times B) \cap C$ (all points of $C$ with first coordinate equal to $a_0$) is also non-empty and $\pi_B[(\{a_0 \} \times B) \cap C]$ has a $\le'$-minimum $b_0 \in B$.

Claim: $(a_0, b_0) = \min(C)$. To see this, let $(a,b)\in C$ be arbitrary. Then $a \in \pi_A[C]$ and so $a_0 \le a$ by minimility of $a_0$ in that set. If $a_0 < a$ we are done, as then $(a_0, b_0) \le_l (a,b)$ by the definition of the lexicographic order. So it remains to consider the case $a_0=a$, but then $(a,b) \in (\{a_0 \} \times B) \cap C$ and so $b \in \pi_B[(\{a_0 \} \times B) \cap C]$ and $b_0 \le' b$ by minimality of $b_0$ again. Now, from $a_0 \le a$ and $b_0 \le' b$ we conclude $(a_0, b_0) \le_l (a,b)$ again by the definition of $\le_l$.
The claim has been shown.